# Sympy: Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse for MatrixSymbol

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math, matrix-inverse

The following code inverts a matrix A in sympy.

```
import sympy
from sympy import MatrixSymbol

A = MatrixSymbol('A', 3, 3)    
A.I
```

I'd like to know how to obtain the pseudo-inverse of A. This is because I am doing a calculation with generic singular square matrices A and products of the type A * A.pinv show up, and I don't want sympy to simplify these to the identity matrix, which is what happens if I use the inverse instead of the pseudo-inverse.

Note that there is a pinv() function in sympy, however, as far as I can tell it only works for Matrix (i.e., matrices with specified elements) and not MatrixSymbol (i.e., generic matrices).

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: SymPy does not have an expression type for the pseudo-inverse of a matrix expression (rather than an explicit matrix). There are explicit formulas that you can use if you can make assumptions about the rank of the matrix: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse#Special_cases